# Amplify Datastore.Observe skipping subscription

Tags: datastore, aws-amplify

> I configure my Datastore with sync Expression like this

```
syncExpression(MyTable, () => {
 return data => data.tenant_id('eq', "123")
 }
```

> i recieve all updation in datastore.observe() but when i update "tenant_id" 123 to 345 then datastore subscription doesnot work on this case.

> How do i get change in datastore on doing this scenario, I want subscription on this case to complete my relevant task